# show items that has no match in the DBtable as item_name = 0

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my tables in my database.

```
order_items
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
|   order_id    |     datesales     |       qty      |    product_id |
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
|     1         |      timestamp    |        5       |      1        |
|     1         |      timestamp    |        10      |      2        |
|     1         |      timestamp    |        10      |      3        |
|     1         |      timestamp    |        10      |      4        |
|     2         |      timestamp    |        5       |      1        |
|     2         |      timestamp    |        10      |      2        |
|     2         |      timestamp    |        10      |      3        |
|     2         |      timestamp    |        10      |      4        |
|     3         |      timestamp    |        5       |      1        |
|     3         |      timestamp    |        10      |      2        |
|     3         |      timestamp    |        10      |      3        |
|     3         |      timestamp    |        10      |      4        |
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

```
products
+---------------+-------------------+
|    id         |       names       |
+---------------+-------------------+
|     1         |     ice cream     |
|     2         |     iced tea      |
|     3         |       cake        |
|     4         |   orange juice    |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

this is the query I'm using

```
select p.names, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) sum_product_qty
from products p
left join orders_item o on p.id = o.product_id
WHERE date(datesales) <= curdate() and date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by p.id, p.names
```

what I want to happen is that the query shows the items that has 0 match on the other table as such

```
orange juice = 18
cake         = 24
iced tea     = 0
ice cream    = 0
```

with the current query, it only shows results like this

```
orange juice = 18
cake         = 24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditions on the `left join`ed tables to the `on` clause of the join. Otherwise, they become mandatory and records that had no match are evicted from the resultset (in other words, your `left join` becomes an `inner join`).

```
select p.names, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) sum_product_qty
from products p
left join orders_item o 
    on p.id = o.product_id
     and date(o.datesales) <= curdate() 
     and date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by p.id, p.names
```

Comment: duuuude, you again! I really am thankful for your help! I forgot to add the datesales on my previous question. Thank you for the quick response!